# How to write unit test with to check if list which is send to the view by controller is ordered correctly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a controller which orders `Order`s by there `Category.Sequence` property as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Return orders of this Date
        var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

        var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Product)
            .Where(o => o.Date == currentDate && o.IsConfirmed == false)
            .OrderBy(o => o.Product.Category.Sequence == null)
            .ThenBy(o => o.Product.Category.Sequence)
            .ToList();

        return View("Index" ,new ShoppingListViewModel(orders, db.Locks.Any(l => l.Date == DateTime.Today)));
    }
```

Where the ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class ShoppingListViewModel
{
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; private set; }
    (...)
}
```

Now I want to unittest if this works. To do this I have the following unittest:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestShoppingListControllerOrderBySequenceNumber()
{
    // Arrange
    var db = this.getTestDBContext();
    var controller = new ShoppingListController(db);

    // Invoke
    var viewResult = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
    var ordersFromView = (ViewModels.ShoppingListViewModel)viewResult.Model;
    var orderList = ordersFromView.Orders;

    // Assert
    var expected = 2;
    var actual = orderList.First().Product.Category.Sequence;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual,
        string.Format("The first order in the list should have" + 
        " Sequence {0}, but had Sequence {1}", expected, actual));

}
```

Where GetTestDBContext does the following:

```
 private IContext getTestDBContext()
        {
                        // Arrange 
            var memoryItems = new FakeDbSet<Order>
            {
                // Categorie 1 and unconfirmed
                new Order { OrderId = 1, 
                            UnitPrice = 1.00M, 
                            Quantity = 2, 
                            Date = DateTime.Today, 
                            IsConfirmed = false,
                            ProductId = 1,
                            User = new User { Name = "Piet", Email = "piet@paulusma.nl", IsAvailable = true }, 
                            Product = new Product {
                                Category = new Category {CategoryId = 1, Name = "Categorie1", Sequence = 3}, 
                                Name = "Testproduct",
                                Price = 1.00M,
                                Visible = true
                            }
                },
                // Categorie 2 and unconfirmed
                new Order { OrderId = 2, 
                            UnitPrice = 2.00M, 
                            Quantity = 1, 
                            Date = DateTime.Today, 
                            IsConfirmed = false, 
                            ProductId = 2,
                            User = new User { Name = "Kees", Email = "Kees@DeHond.nl", IsAvailable = true }, 
                            Product = new Product {
                                Category = new Category {CategoryId = 2, Name = "Categorie2", Sequence = 2}, 
                                Name = "Testproduct2",
                                Price = 2.00M,
                                Visible = true
                            }
                },
                // Categorie 2 and confirmed
                new Order { OrderId = 2, 
                            UnitPrice = 1.00M, 
                            Quantity = 1, 
                            Date = DateTime.Today, 
                            IsConfirmed = true, 
                            ProductId = 3,
                            User = new User { Name = "Jan", Email = "Jan@DeBouvrier.de", IsAvailable = true }, 
                            Product = new Product {
                                Category = new Category {CategoryId = 2, Name = "Categorie2", Sequence = 2}, 
                                Name = "Testproduct2",
                                Price = 3.10M,
                                Visible = true
                            }
                },
            };
```

So `Category` named "Categorie2" With `CategoryId`2 has `Sequence` 2 and another `Category` named `Categorie1` has `Sequence` is 3.

The unit test returns:

> Test Name:    TestShoppingListControllerOrderBySequenceNumber Test
>   Outcome:  Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.0141778
>
> Result Message:   Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2>. Actual:<3>. The
>   first order in the list should have Sequence 2, but had sequence 3

Since expected was the `Sequence` 2 and I got the `Category.Sequence` 3 value, apparently the `TestMethod` does not return an ordered list by `Category.Sequence` as defined in the controller.

How can I accomplish that the `ordersFromView` property in the `TestMethod` to actually return the ordered sequence as it comes from the controller?

Comment: Notice that you are eager loading product but not the product's category.

Comment: @Ben What do you mean?